# create module function alias by import or assignment

Tags: python

Say I have import a module by using

```
import m
```

and now I want an alias to its function, I can use

```
from m import f as n
```

or

```
n = m.f
```

I think there is no difference, is one preferred than another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, as far as using the object `n` is concerned.

There is a slight logical difference: the first way will leave a name `m` bound in scope, and the second way will not.  Though, the `m` module would still get loaded into `sys.modules` with either approach.

Using the import statement for this is more commonly seen.

Comment: I'm not sure what ` leave a name m bound in scope` means. since if I can write `n=m.f`, isn't m always bound in scope?

Comment: It means if you do `from m import f as n` then `m` will still raise a `NameError`, even though the module has been imported.

Answer (score 0):

Use the first one if you only will need to get f. Use the second one if you need to import other things than f (m is still there). Other than that, they are the same.